# @IBOutlet by default should be private or internal in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet

@IBOutlets are usually not accessed from outside its View Controller. Why aren't they set to private as default when created in Xcode? What is the best practice to follow?

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the best practice, you could add a `fileprivate` or`private` attribute.

This helps you to keep all views properties privately and encapsulate all the elements needed to work with the user interface, and made other fields `internal` or`public` if necessary.

You could use `internal` attribute if you want to use property in other classes or structures or`public` attribute if in the future you would use it in the library.

For example, the property of the User datatype on the Profile screen could be internal (by default), and usernameLabel or avatarImageView could be `fileprivate` or`private`.

And, of course, to avoid unnecessary views properties usage.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it's a leftover from the old Objective-C times, but now when we have Swift and we want everything nice and safe [it is indeed the best practice to set @IBOutlets to private](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-iboutlets-private/).

There's not one reason why it should be internal, there's many reasons why it should be private which are obvious so I'm not going to list them.

Answer (score 1):

Because one might or might not want to make them private. While keeping each view controller somewhat atomic keeps complexity down and keeping methods and properties private helps achieve this, there are cases in which it is appropriate to pass information directly between controllers. For example, one may use child view controllers to allow reuse of a complicated component.